# Error:(32, 9) Failed to resolve: com.google.api-client:google-api-clientandroid:1.17.0-rc

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After trying to add the following to build.gradle:

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-clientandroid:1.17.0-rc') 
{exclude module: 'httpclient'}
```

and

```
compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-clientgson:1.17.0-rc')
{exclude module: 'httpclient'}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error:(32, 9) Failed to resolve: com.google.api-client:google-api-clientandroid:1.17.0-rc
```

and

```
Error:(36, 9) Failed to resolve: com.google.http-client:google-http-clientgson:1.17.0-rc
```

Why am I getting these errors?  How do I add these dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Change `compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-clientandroid:1.17.0-rc') 
{exclude module: 'httpclient'}` and `compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-clientgson:1.17.0-rc') {exclude module: 'httpclient'}` to `compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }`

clientgson changed to client-gson

clientadnroid changed to client-android